# Google reCAPTCHA shows a warning on the Data Explorer

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I played around with the Data Explorer for StackOverflow. I get a Google reCAPTCHA to confirm I'm a human, but there was the following:

[image]

This is working and I get the result of the query (with the above input). Reloading the reCAPTCHA doesn't change the image. The Data Explorer seems to use a older version (version 1 ;)) of the Google reCAPTCHA.

Comment: cross site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305988/recaptcha-v1-is-shutting-down-on-march-31-but-sede-still-uses-it and it is being worked on. Expect a fix in 6 to 8 days., they even [planned a maintenance window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307744/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-march-17-2018-at-1300-utc-9am-us-eastern?cb=1) ... wait ... that might be for something else ...

Comment: @rene - Thank you. I didn't found that question. I can send a query and get the result, but the captcha is not working as it should.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I believe it works when you don't put the year as 2013? :p

Comment: You just need to type in "V1 shutdown" for it to work.

Comment: @Laurel It works with **any** text with the length larger than 0.